# how to convert a list to a dataframe with a specific rule?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list `lst`, and I want to convert it to a pandas dataframe object. An element which has the character `:` will be chosen as a column name. And elements after the chosen element will be the values.

```
lst = ['k1：', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'k2：', 'b1', 'k3：', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'k4：', 'd1']
```

and I want this:

```
              k1    k2            k3    k4
0   [a1, a2, a3]    b1  [c1, c2, c3]    d1
```

Help will be appreciated!

Comment: looks like you have to run through the list once and construct a dict and use that dict to construct the dataframe.

Comment: right, that's what I want to do.

Comment: @running man I posted sample code below.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized solution using `list comprehension`, `pandas` and `numpy`:

```
# Split the list to values and columns
cols = [x[:2] for x in lst if "：" in x]
vals = [x for x in lst if "：" not in x]

print(cols)
print(vals)

['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4']
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'd1']
```

Create dataframe out of the lists

```
s = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=['values'])
s['letter'] = s['values'].str.slice(stop=1)
s = pd.DataFrame(s.groupby('letter')['values'].apply(list).reset_index(drop=True))
df = pd.DataFrame(s.to_numpy().reshape(1,4), columns=cols, index=[0])

print(df)
             k1    k2            k3    k4
0  [a1, a2, a3]  [b1]  [c1, c2, c3]  [d1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and a `for` loop to restructure `lst`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for i in lst:
    if '：' in i:
        current_key = i
    else:
        d[current_key].append(i)

df = pd.DataFrame([d.values()], columns=d.keys())
```

[out]

```
            k1：   k2：           k3：   k4：
0  [a1, a2, a3]  [b1]  [c1, c2, c3]  [d1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code:

I first split the list based on `":"` in value  `e.g [['k1：', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3'],['k3：', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3'],....]` and then created a dictionary 1st value as a key and rest of the values as a value in a list `e.g {'k1':['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],....}`. Created the dataframe using dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd

lst = ['k1：', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'k2：', 'b1', 'k3：', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'k4：', 'd1']

#----- SPlit list based on ":" in values ----#
def group(seq, sep):
    g = []
    for el in seq:
        if sep in str(el):
            yield g
            g = []
        g.append(el)
    yield g

result = list(group(lst, '：'))

Data = {}
for l in result:
    if len(l):
        key = l[0]
        values = l[1:]
        Data[key] = [values]

DF = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Data)
print(DF)
```

Output:

```
            k1：   k2：           k3：   k4：
0  [a1, a2, a3]   [b1]   [c1, c2, c3]   [d1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
lst = ['k1: ', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'k2:', 'b1', 'k3:', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'k4:', 'd1']
ret_dict = {}
last_key = None

for key in lst:
    pos = key.find(':')
    if pos > -1:
        last_key = key[:pos]
        ret_dict[last_key] = [[]]
    else:
        ret_dict[last_key][0].append(key)

pd.DataFrame(ret_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {}
temp = []

for i in lst:
    if ':' in i:
        if temp:
            d[h] = str(temp)
            temp = []
        h = i.split(':')[0]    
    else:
        temp.append(i)
d[h] = temp    

pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0])
```

**output**

```
                   k1      k2                  k3  k4
0  ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']  ['b1']  ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']  d1
```